# How to use async/await inside effects angular NgRx?

Tags: angular, async-await, promise, ngrx, effects

I'm running this code :

```
 public customCommand$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(appActions.customCommand),
          tap(action => console.log(action)),
          switchMap( (action) => {
            const { commandInput } = action;
            const commandOutput = this.shellExecutor.executeCommand(commandInput);

            return this.generalApiService
                         .sendCustomCommandResult(commandInput, commandOutput).pipe(
                map((res) => appActions.customCommandSuccess({ commandOutput: res })),
              catchError(() => of(appActions.checkHebrewLocaleError())),
            );
          }),
          catchError(() => of(appActions.customCommandError())),
        ),
    );
```

and I need to await for **commandOutput** answer, the problem that *commandOutput* return a Promise and i've try to use async/await and i'm getting an error.
attaching a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Execute command and sendCustomCommand are async operations - chain two switchMaps or two effects.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution, just wrap with switchMap the action that I need to use with async/await answer and than pass the result to another switchMap, not sure that is the best way but it works.

```
 public customCommand$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(appActions.customCommand),
          switchMap(async (action) => {
            const { commandInput } = action;
            const commandOutput = await this.shellExecutor.executeCommand(commandInput);

            return { commandInput, commandOutput};
          }),
          switchMap((commandState: CommandState) => {
            const {commandInput, commandOutput} = commandState;

            return this.generalApiService
              .sendCustomCommandResult(commandInput, commandOutput).pipe(
                switchMap((res) => {

                  return of(appActions.customCommandSuccess({ commandOutput: res }));
                }),
                catchError(() => of(appActions.customCommandError())),
              );
          }),
          catchError(() => of(appActions.customCommandError())),
        ),
    );
```